# How to create a form in Django from a model with multiple ForeignKey and ManytoManyField fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am a Django newbie. I cannot figure out how to create a form that properly displays my model, which has two `ForeignKey` fields and three `ManytoManyFields`. I am familiar with creating forms from more simple models, but I'm stuck on this one. So far, I've tried `ModelForm` and used `ModelChoiceField` for `ForeignKey` relationships, but that did not work. When viewing the form, the fields options did not render. I then tried inlineformset_factory but I could not find helpful examples. Any help is appreciated.
I am trying to create CreateView, UpdateView, and DeleteView options for the model.

`models.py`

```
    class Animal(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=False)
        **atype = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)**
        **ageGroup = models.ForeignKey(AgeGroup, max_length=300, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)**
        ageYears = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        ageMonths = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=SEX, blank=False, null=False, default='NA')
        city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        **breedGroup = models.ManyToManyField(BreedGroup, blank=False)**
        **breed = models.ManyToManyField(Breed, blank=False)**
        tagLine = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
        goodWithCats = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default='Not Enough Information')
        goodWithDogs = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default='Not Enough Information')
        goodWKids = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default='Not Enough Information')
        profilePic = ResizedImageField(size=[300, 450], quality=100, upload_to='media/', default='', null=True, blank=True, keep_meta=False)
        **contact = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetails, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=False, null=True)**
```

`forms.py`

```
    class AnimalDetailsForm(ModelForm):
        ftype = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Type.objects.all())         #doesn't work
        ageGroup = ModelChoiceField(queryset=AgeGroup.objects.all()) #doesn't work
        #breed = what method to use?
        #breedGroup = what method to use? 

        class Meta:
            model = Animal
            exclude = ['ftype', 'ageGroup', 'breed', 'breedGroup']
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in the Meta of your form you are excluding the fields you are trying to get data for. It should say

```
class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['type', 'ageGroup', 'breed', 'breedGroup']
```

Docs consulted: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/

**edit, removed comment about using type as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks. I will correct keyword instance. I excluded those fields because I targeted them (or tried to) separately, above Meta class. I first tried a simple ModelForm with `fields` set to `__all__` but that did not work. I'm starting to think that I need to create a custom form and, as a newbie, that seems a bit daunting.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the keyword thing. It's not one of the reseved keywords. However it's best practice to have descriptive variable names. So maybe saying what type it is e.g. 'dog_type'. Variable names are usually seperated with underscores in python and not with mixedCase.

Comment: That said, I don't think you need to make a custom form since the problem is rendering a form with the appropriate fields at all. What you need to do is try simplified versions. Only one field, one form. That way you can find out exactly which fields are causing issues and try to solve them directly before piling them all together. With the mass of fields and relationships you have it will be hard to trouble shoot.

Comment: Just out of curiosity would something render if your form looked like this?

`class AnimalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Animal`

Comment: Yeah, good point. I was able to figure it out. materialize.css was overriding bootstrap which was preventing form fields to render.

Comment: @robline I got an error when trying that, stating that I needed either fields or exclude.